# How do I repeat/loop code so that it runs multiples until I ask it to stop?

Tags: python, list, loops, random, repeat

I have a piece of python code which I am generating 3 random integers between 0 and 100:

```
list1=random.sample(0, 100),3)
if sum(list1)=20:
    print(list1)
else:
    pass #do nothing
```

I want:

1. The sum of the three generated numbers to equate to 20 and if it doesn't equal 20 to then repeat the code again until it comes up with 3 numbers that do equal 20.
2. To keep doing this repeat N number of times so it has generated multiple lists that add up to 20.

Can anybody help? My ideas so far are something to do with loop functions but don't know where to start.

Comment: You're asking us to solve your homework assignment. Not cool. The very first line in your attempted solution isn't even valid Python syntax. You need to make a good faith effort to solve the problem. Something you haven't demonstrated. FWIW, for your situation I would recommend `randint()` rather than `sample()`. Simple call it three times to get your values. Then sum them and break out of the loop if the sum is 20.

Answer (score 2):

```
list1=random.sample(0, 100),3)
while sum(list1) != 20:
    list1=random.sample(0, 100),3)
print(list1)
```

Comment: random.sample needs a population as 1st argument. So this probably won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use a while loop:

```
while True:
    list1=random.sample(0, 100),3)
    if sum(list1)=20:
        print(list1)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing something until something else happens is a `while`-loop. Doing something a given number of times is a `for`-loop.

Let's say you want 3 entries in your list. This is a `for`-loop with a range of 3:

```
for i in range(3):
  do_something()
```

You don't know, when the random sample will add-up to 20, so this is a `while`-loop:

```
result = []
list1 = []
while sum(list1) != 20:
  list1 = random.sample(range(100),3)
result.append(list1)
```

So putting that together will give:

```
result = []
for i in range(3):
  list1 = []
  while sum(list1) != 20:
    list1 = random.sample(range(100),3)
  result.append(list1)
```